# How to override ONE linter setting for ONE file in VSCode?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

VSCode linter settings are described in `.vscode/settings.js`

I want to change ONE linter setting for ONE file.
To be specific, I want to change the `"dart.lineLength": 80` to `"dart.lineLength": 100`

ESLint has next syntax for file linting

```
.my-exclusive-file.js

/*eslint max-len: ["error", { "code": 100 }]*/
```

Has VSCode linter something like that?

`files.exclude` in `.vscode/settings.json` disables ALL rules for this file but I want to override only one.

I want something like

```
.my-exclusive-file.dart

/*settings "dart.lineLength": 100*/
```